# Is it possible to see which bazel target propagates the -lpthread flag?

Tags: android, tensorflow, pthreads, bazel

When building TensorFlow with a custom toolchain (android arm64-v8a target) with Bazel, the final shared library has a dependency on `libpthread.so` even though it is not necessary for Android builds. The library works fine using a dummy library with the same name.

I suppose there is some external dependency that propagates the link flag since I have removed all occurences of `lpthread/pthread` in the TensorFlow repository.

Is it possible somehow to track which target adds a specific link flag with Bazel? The `-s` flag unfortunately only shows the final link command.

Comment: `aquery` could help. Your target and its dependencies (`bazel aquery 'deps(tgt)'`) may provide you with the insight where along the way a specific option has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bazel query](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query.html) is the tool for this. This command will give you all the transitive dependencies with `-lpthread` (or alternate spellings like `-pthread` or `-Wl,-lpthread`) in their linkopts:

```
bazel query 'attr(linkopts, "pthread", deps(//my:target))'
```